# MySQL inserting 0000-00-00 or wrong value in DATE field

Tags: mysql, date, datepicker

I am struggling to insert correct date in MySQL Date column. My code is as below.

For the date field, I am using [Air Datepicker](http://t1m0n.name/air-datepicker/docs/) plugin

```
<!-- HTML-->

<div class="<?php ab_form_group_class( 'availability' ) ?>">
    <label for="age" class="control-label">What is your availability date?</label>
    <input type="text" name="availability" class="datepicker-here form-control" id="availability"
           placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" <?php ab_post_value('availability') ?>>
    <?php ab_form_error( 'availability' ) ?>
</div>

<!-- Javascript -->   

$('.datepicker-here').datepicker({
    language: 'en',
    todayButton: true,
    inline: true,
    autoClose: true,
    language: {
        days: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
        daysShort: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
        daysMin: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
        months: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
        monthsShort: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        today: 'Today',
        clear: 'Clear',
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy', // I have tried setting yyyy-mm-dd but this too didn't solves
        timeFormat: 'hh:ii aa',
        firstDay: 0
    }
});


<?php

// SQL Column
`availability` DATE NOT NULL,

// PHP Code

$availability   = $_POST[ 'availability' ];

// when I set input format to dd/mm/yyyy
$availability = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($availability));
```

The result I am getting in MySQL is **`0000-00-00`** or even I have tried to use normal text field *(without datepicker)* that time it is inserting wrong date value.

## Update

After @bansi suggestion, I have tried this. It is converting format correctly but still MySQL column inserting `0000-00-00`

```
$available_date = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'd/m/Y', $availability );
$availability   = $available_date->format( 'Y-m-d' );
```

Comment: what is the output of `print_r($_POST[ 'availability' ]);`. `strtotime` can get confused on `dd/mm/yyyy` date format. try using [DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: @bansi I have checked with var_dump and it is giving correct output with the date format set in the input field. For instance `2017-03-01` for `yyyy-mm-dd` and `01/03/2017` for `dd/mm/yyyy`. These formats are for the `datepicker` plugin set in javascript.

Comment: check what is in `$availability` after `date` call. also with `dd/mm/yyyy` format strtotime interprets date as `m/d/y` (American date). so use DateTime class to create proper date.

Comment: Please try this

`STR_TO_DATE($availability,'%d/%m/%Y');` when you put that variable in `INSERT` statement.

Comment: @bansi I have tried DateTime::createFromFormat and it is converting format properly. This is the end result `2017-03-29` from `29/03/2017` but still, MySQL inserts value is `0000-00-00`  Please see my updates on question. I don't understand what I am doing wrong!

Comment: can you please show your query?

Comment: @prakashtank Oh! my bad. I am using wordpress `$wpdb->insert($data, $format)` and I was using `%d` for date format and change it with `%s` and it is not inserting date correctly.  Just wonder to know, why MySQL date format has to be set to `%s` Is it consider as a `STRING`?

Comment: @CodeLover : Yes because date also have some other chars too. and integer format don't allow that. that's my understanding not sure.

Comment: @prakashtank okay cool... thanks..!